# Looping through a list from a specific key to the end of the list

Tags: python

in Python how do i loop through list starting at a key and not the beginning.
e.g.

```
l = ['a','b','c','d']
```

loop through `l` but starting at b e.g. `l[1]`

Comment: Do you want to start at the second position in the list, or do you want to start at the first occurrence of the "key" `'b'`?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

### The straightforward answer

Just use [slicing](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists):

```
>>> l = ['a','b','c','d']
>>> for i in l[1:]:
...     print(i)
... 
b
c
d
```

It will generate a new list with the items before `1` removed:

```
>>> l[1:]
['b', 'c', 'd']
```

### A more efficient alternative

Alternatively, if your list is huge, or you are going to slice the list a lot of times, you can use [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice). It returns an iterator, avoiding copying the entire rest of the list, saving memory:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> s = itertools.islice(l, 1, None)
>>> for i in s:
...     print(i)
... 
b
c
d
```

Also note that, since it returns an interator, you can iterate over it only once:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> s = itertools.islice(l, 1, None)
>>> for i in s:
...     print(i)
... 
b
c
d
>>> for i in s:
...     print(i)
>>>
```

### How to choose

I find slicing clearer/more pleasant to read but `itertools.islice()` can be more efficient. I would use slicing most of the time, relying on `itertools.islice()` when my list has thousands of items, or when I iterate over hundreds of different slices.

Answer (score 5):

My 5 cent:

```
start_from = 'b'

for val in l[l.index(start_from ) if start_from  in l else 0:]:
   print val
```

Answer (score 4):

This will loop through items in l beginning with 1:

```
for i in l[1:]:
    #do something with i
```

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for slicing a list like this is: `l[1:]`

To answer your question:

```
for i in l[1:]:
    print i
```